# Cannot cite references as [1]-[7] format

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am following all the rules for citation, still, I am unable to cite the references in e.g. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BQYx.png)-[10] format. Please see the attached figure below, while following is the .tex version that generated it.

```
...MC and the core-network \cite{chae2013novel,jangsher2016backhaul,jaziri2016offloading,sui2012potential,khan2017outage,khan2016moving,chae2012dynamic,haider2011spectral,MShinPublicSafety}.
```

[image]

The following is my bibliography insertion

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{test_bib}
```

Comment: Look at your style and what's allowed there, as it seems to be a paper template. `natbib` (not what you want, probably) and `cite` packages have the desired functionality.

Comment: If I use \usepackage{cite}, then I get the error: "paragraph ended before @citex was complete". I looked for it, and all the {-} pairs are complete.
I used \usepackage{natbib}, but it does not help

Comment: When you added the instruction `\usepackage{cite}` to your preamble, did you first delete the `.aux` and `.bbl` file before running a full recompile cycle (LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, & LaTeX)?

Comment: Yes, I did! still the same error.

Comment: Please provide a MWEB people can compile to reproduce the output you show. If this is for a journal or conference, though, they probably tell you which style and packages to use to get the format they want.

Comment: By MWEB cfr refers to https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the solution by using the following two packages together.

```
\usepackage{mciteplus}
\usepackage{cite}
```

Note that I have not used any variation of `\usepackage{natbib}`.

PS. this thing happened with hit-and-trial. I myself don't know the logic behind this. Before compiling, do clear all the auxiliary files.

Answer (score 1):

Use: `\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}`